# Complex Database Queries in yii2 with Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, yii2

TL;DR 
I have a query that works in RAW SQL but i have had little success recreating it with query builder or active record.

---

I am working on a web application based off of the yii2 advanced application template. I have written a database query and implemented it with findbysql() returning the correct records but am having trouble translating this into active record.

I originally wanted to allow the user to modify (filter) the results by means of a search form(user & date), however i have since realized that implementing filters on the gridview with active records would be smoother.

I have gotten simple queries to work however am unsure of how to implement one with this many joins. Many examples used sub queries but my attempts failed to return any records at all. I figured before I attempt filters i need to transcribe this query first.

### *videoController.php*

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $sql =  'SELECT videos.idvideo, videos.filelocation, events.event_type, events.event_timestamp
                    FROM (((ispy.videos videos
                        INNER JOIN ispy.cameras cameras
                            ON (videos.cameras_idcameras = cameras.idcameras))
                        INNER JOIN ispy.host_machines host_machines
                            ON (cameras.host_machines_idhost_machines =
                                    host_machines.idhost_machines))
                        INNER JOIN ispy.events events
                            ON (events.host_machines_idhost_machines =
                                    host_machines.idhost_machines))
                        INNER JOIN ispy.staff staff
                            ON (events.staff_idreceptionist = staff.idreceptionist)
                    WHERE     (staff.idreceptionist = 182)
                            AND (events.event_type IN (23, 24))
                            AND (events.event_timestamp BETWEEN videos.start_time
                                   AND videos.end_time)';
        $query = Videos::findBySql($sql);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' =>  $query,
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);

}
```

### Failed Attempt

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Videos::find()
    ->innerJoin('cameras',  'videos.cameras_idcameras = cameras.idcameras')
    ->innerJoin('host_machines',  'cameras.host_machines_idhost_machines = host_machines.idhost_machines')
    ->innerJoin('events',  'events.host_machines_idhost_machines =  host_machines.idhost_machines')
    ->innerJoin('staff',  'events.staff_idreceptionist = staff.idreceptionist')
    ->where('staff.idreceptionist = 182')
    ->andWhere(['events.event_type' => [23,24]])
    ->andwhere(['between', 'events.event_timestamp', 'videos.start_time', 'videos.end_time']);


    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' =>  $query,
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);

}
```

### Portion of View

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'idvideo',
        'event_type',
        'event_timestamp',
        'filelocation',
        //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Please let me know if i need to be more specific or include any additional information.

---

Thanks ahead

Comment: So i noticed that my last inner join is actually outside of the select statement followed by the conditions and am attempting to recreate this.

Comment: Videos model don't have any relation?

Comment: @InsaneSkull they do, i assumed because the raw SQL worked i did not need to include my relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i will assume, based on the question you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41575231/374509) you liked in comments that **you provided the entire query**
(no other fields, that you took out just to show sample code)

therefore, if you only need only the fields specified in `SELECT` statement, you can optimize your query quite a bit:

first off, you're joining with `host_machines` only to link `cameras` and `events`, but have the same key `host_machines_idhost_machines` on both, so that's not needed, you can directly:

```
    INNER JOIN events events
        ON (events.host_machines_idhost_machines =
            cameras.host_machines_idhost_machines))
```

secondly, the join with `ispy.staff`, the only used field is `idreceptionist` in `WHERE` clause, that field exists in `events` as well so we can drop it completly

the final query here:

```
SELECT videos.idvideo, videos.filelocation, events.event_type, events.event_timestamp
FROM videos videos
    INNER JOIN cameras cameras
        ON videos.cameras_idcameras = cameras.idcameras
    INNER JOIN events events
        ON events.host_machines_idhost_machines =
                cameras.host_machines_idhost_machines
WHERE     (events.staff_idreceptionist = 182)
        AND (events.event_type IN (23, 24))
        AND (events.event_timestamp BETWEEN videos.start_time
               AND videos.end_time)
```

should output the same records as the one in your question, without any identitcal rows
some video duplicates will still exists due to one to many relation between `cameras` and `events`

---

now to the yii side of things,
you have to define some relations on the **Videos** model

```
// this is pretty straight forward, `videos`.`cameras_idcameras` links to a 
// single camera (one-to-one)
public function getCamera(){
    return $this->hasOne(Camera::className(), ['idcameras' => 'cameras_idcameras']);
}
// link the events table using `cameras` as a pivot table (one-to-many)
public function getEvents(){
    return $this->hasMany(Event::className(), [
        // host machine of event        =>  host machine of camera (from via call)
        'host_machines_idhost_machines' => 'host_machines_idhost_machines'
    ])->via('camera');
}
```

the **VideoController** and the search function itself

```
public function actionIndex() {
    // this will be the query used to create the ActiveDataProvider
    $query =Video::find()
        ->joinWith(['camera', 'events'], true, 'INNER JOIN')
        ->where(['event_type' => [23, 24], 'staff_idreceptionist' => 182])
        ->andWhere('event_timestamp BETWEEN videos.start_time AND videos.end_time');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' =>  $query,
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

yii will treat each video as a single record (based on pk), that means that all video duplicates are
removed. you will have single videos, each with multiple events so you wont be able to use `'event_type'`
and `'event_timestamp'` in the view but you can declare some getters inside **Video** model to show that info:

```
public function getEventTypes(){
    return implode(', ', ArrayHelper::getColumn($this->events, 'event_type'));
}

public function getEventTimestamps(){
    return implode(', ', ArrayHelper::getColumn($this->events, 'event_timestamp'));
}
```

and the view use:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'idvideo',
        'eventTypes',
        'eventTimestamps',
        'filelocation',
        //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

---

**edit**:
if you want to keep the video duplicates, declare the two columns from `events` inside **Video** model

```
public $event_type, $event_timestamp;
```

keep the original `GridView` setup, and add a `select` and `indexBy` this to the query inside **VideoController**:

```
$q  = Video::find()
    // spcify fields
    ->addSelect(['videos.idvideo', 'videos.filelocation', 'events.event_type', 'events.event_timestamp'])
    ->joinWith(['camera', 'events'], true, 'INNER JOIN')
    ->where(['event_type' => [23, 24], 'staff_idreceptionist' => 182])
    ->andWhere('event_timestamp BETWEEN videos.start_time AND videos.end_time')
    // force yii to treat each row as distinct
    ->indexBy(function () {
        static $count;
        return ($count++);
    });
```

---

### update

a direct `staff` relation to `Video` is currently somewhat problematic since that is more than one table away from it.
there's an issue about it [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5341)

however, you add the `staff` table by linking it to the **Event** model,

```
public function getStaff() {
    return $this->hasOne(Staff::className(), ['idreceptionist' => 'staff_idreceptionist']);
}
```

that will allow you to query like this:

```
->joinWith(['camera', 'events', 'events.staff'], true, 'INNER JOIN')
```

**Filtering** will require some small updates on the controller, view and a `SarchModel`
here's a minimal implementation:

```
class VideoSearch extends Video
{
    public $eventType;
    public $eventTimestamp;
    public $username;

    public function rules() {
        return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
            [['eventType', 'eventTimestamp', 'username'], 'safe']
        ]);
    }

    public function search($params) {
        // add/adjust only conditions that ALWAYS apply here:
        $q = parent::find()
            ->joinWith(['camera', 'events', 'events.staff'], true, 'INNER JOIN')
            ->where([
                'event_type' => [23, 24],
                // 'staff_idreceptionist' => 182
                // im guessing this would be the username we want to filter by
            ])
            ->andWhere('event_timestamp BETWEEN videos.start_time AND videos.end_time');

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $q]);

        if (!$this->validate())
            return $dataProvider;

        $this->load($params);

        $q->andFilterWhere([
            'idvideo'                => $this->idvideo,
            'events.event_type'      => $this->eventType,
            'events.event_timestamp' => $this->eventTimestamp,
            'staff.username'         => $this->username,
        ]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

controller:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new VideoSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('test', [
        'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

and the view

```
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'  => $searchModel,
    'columns'      => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'idvideo',
        'filelocation',
        [
            'attribute' => 'eventType',     // from VideoSearch::$eventType (this is the one you filter by)
            'value'     => 'eventTypes'     // from Video::getEventTypes() that i suggested yesterday
            // in hindsight, this could have been named better, like Video::formatEventTypes or smth
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'eventTimestamp',
            'value'     => 'eventTimestamps'
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'username',
            'value'     => function($video){
                return implode(', ', ArrayHelper::map($video->events, 'idevent', 'staff.username'));
            }
        ],
        //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have implemented it as instructed and aside from a few typos (due to my ambiguous naming) have achieved the desired results. I am working through understanding your solution now but have awarded the bounty in the mean time.

Comment: In hindsight i should have included the schema as i do have more fields than what was shown in the query (your assumption). The only problem  i have now is the fields in the staff table. I want to be able to search/filter videos by user and date range. From what i understand i need to define one additional relation and include staff in the joinWith statement on the controller. However because the relation between videos and staff is many to many i would need an intermittent table correct? @csminb

Comment: @NickR i just added an update on filtering. the relation from videos to staff, the way i understand it, passes trough 2 tables (videos > cameras > events > staff) going directly from going directly from videos to staff in yii will cause some errors when eager loading. you can however join with a nested relation ('event.staff') as i exemplified in the answer

Comment: @NickR also, sorry, out of habit, i switched classnames to singular

Comment: Thanks again for the response. There is a additional table, host_machines, between cameras and events but i believe getEvents() accounts for that. I had read about that problem with the many to many but was unable to get a work around implemented. When linking the staff table to the events (before filtering) i get this error [Invalid Parameter - common\models\Events has no relation named "staff".] My events table has a gii relation getStaffidReceptionist(). i attempted to add a getStaff() relation on idreceptionist=staffidreception, which removed the error but left the records "(not set)".

Comment: I figured out my error. I was unable to get the related column to display in the gridview despite seeing the sql in debug function as expected. I added an addSelect() statement to my query and specified the tables for each field and my problem was solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to have 2 queries. The first one to get the ids of the videos that fit your search, the second query theone that uses those ids and feeds your `$dataProvider`.

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

...

public function actionIndex()
{
    // This is basically the same query you had before
    $searchResults = Videos::find()
        // change 'id' for the name of your primary key
        ->select('id')
        // we don't really need ActiveRecord instances, better use array
        ->asArray()
        ->innerJoin('cameras', 'videos.cameras_idcameras = cameras.idcameras')
        ->innerJoin('host_machines', 'cameras.host_machines_idhost_machines = host_machines.idhost_machines')
        ->innerJoin('events', 'events.host_machines_idhost_machines =  host_machines.idhost_machines')
        ->innerJoin('staff', 'events.staff_idreceptionist = staff.idreceptionist')
        ->where('staff.idreceptionist = 182')
        ->andWhere(['events.event_type' => [23,24]])
        ->andwhere(['between', 'events.event_timestamp', 'videos.start_time', 'videos.end_time'])
        // query the results
        ->all();

    // this will be the query used to create the ActiveDataProvider
    $query = Videos::find()
        // and we use the results of the previous query to filter this one
        ->where(['id' => ArrayHelper::getColumn($searchResults, 'id')]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' =>  $query,
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess my problem lies in that i don't believe that query works as is. I get no errors with your solution but return 0 records while my raw SQL provides the intended records.