# Yii2 Gridview Displaying 4 identical Pages of Results

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

---

I am working on a web application based off of the yii2 advanced application template. I have written a database query and implemented it with findbysql() returning the correct records via a grid-view generated from the gii CRUD. However for some reason 4 pages of identical results are returned. Each page is showing identical primary keys (1-10) in order, while the element index increases linearly across all 4 pages (1-40).

I have commented out the action column so i figured i did not need to include the CRUD .php files

### *videoController.php*

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $sql =  'SELECT videos.idvideo, videos.filelocation, events.event_type, events.event_timestamp
                    FROM (((ispy.videos videos
                        INNER JOIN ispy.cameras cameras
                            ON (videos.cameras_idcameras = cameras.idcameras))
                        INNER JOIN ispy.host_machines host_machines
                            ON (cameras.host_machines_idhost_machines =
                                    host_machines.idhost_machines))
                        INNER JOIN ispy.events events
                            ON (events.host_machines_idhost_machines =
                                    host_machines.idhost_machines))
                        INNER JOIN ispy.staff staff
                            ON (events.staff_idreceptionist = staff.idreceptionist)
                    WHERE     (staff.idreceptionist = 182)
                            AND (events.event_type IN (23, 24))
                            AND (events.event_timestamp BETWEEN videos.start_time
                                   AND videos.end_time)'; */
        $query = Videos::findBySql($sql);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' =>  $query,
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);

}
```

### View

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'idvideo',
        'event_type',
        'event_timestamp',
        'filelocation',
        //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Please let me know if i need to be more specific or include any additional information.

---

Thanks ahead

Comment: duplicates are caused by the joins most likely, it is a rather.. unorthodox aproach. you can probabbly hack it together by adding a group by statement, or implement it the right way, with ActiveRecord relations. can you post your Video model (with fields and relations)

Comment: Thanks csminb, that is my problem. I actually am attempting to translate this raw sql in a different question and had a suspicion that that might be part of the issue. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574989/complex-database-queries-in-yii2-with-active-record

Comment: Hmm @csminb i am attempting to add more code but the code tags keep not including it all of what i paste. http://pastebin.com/NDaJ7z1V has my video model. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the pagination needs SQL modifier `offset` which has no effect on the result of `findBySql`. See the [Yii doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql()-detail).

You have to use $_GET['page'] and $_GET['per-page'] in your controller, e.g.:

```
$page = array_key_exists('page', $_GET) ? $_GET['page']-1 : 0;
$perPage = array_key_exists('per-page', $_GET) ? $_GET['per-page'] : 30;
$offset = $page * $perPage;

$sql = "SELECT ...
        OFFSET $offset LIMIT $perPage";

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' =>  $query,
     'pagination' => [
         pageSize' => 30,
     ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

also added this in the first part of your linked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41624735/5139881), with explanation

```
SELECT videos.idvideo, videos.filelocation, events.event_type, events.event_timestamp
FROM ((videos videos
    INNER JOIN cameras cameras
        ON (videos.cameras_idcameras = cameras.idcameras))
    INNER JOIN events events
        ON (events.host_machines_idhost_machines =
            cameras.host_machines_idhost_machines))
WHERE (events.staff_idreceptionist = 182)
        AND (events.event_type IN (23, 24))
        AND (events.event_timestamp BETWEEN videos.start_time
               AND videos.end_time);
```